# Prevent corev4.css from loading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding, public-website

i would like to prevent corev4.css from loading for a public site (100% anonymous) to reduce pages size.
any suggestions please ?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent corev4.css when that's the CORE css? What are you trying to accomplish by reducing page size?

Comment: @Mike corev4.css is used for backoffice in my case i use a personalized css, soo i dont need the CORE css

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to accomplish this in a way that suits your goal.  SharePoint will always add its CSS to each page.  You could remove it client-side, but that doesn't solve your issue of reducing page size.

For public-facing sites, I have used Aptimizer (now owned by Riverbed): http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/stingray/stingray_aptimizer.php

Tools like Aptimizer compress, consolidate, etc., everything at the IIS level.  Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's 'impossible', because there is the

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
```

control in the master page which you can conditionally replace with other kinds of references to stylesheets you need on your publishing site.

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: Please read these:
http://www.nothingbutbranding.com/blog/2012/october/add-custom-css-link-to-sharepoint-2010
http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2007/10/08/sharepoint-branding-how-css-works-with-master-pages-part-1/
http://panvega.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/sharepoint-masterpages-css-registrations-approaches/

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a custom control which inherits CssLink, and in that you need to make some logic which prevents the COREV4.css to be loaded based on some condition.

```
public partial class CustomCssLink : CssLink
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a custom master page and remove the 
     < SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/> 
from the markup?

SharePoint will then not add the css file to the request and you will get a much "lighter" page. But then every out of the box control's css will have to be re-entered from your branding project in any case you are using the out of the box controls.

If you are making a public facing site the I assume that you have a custom master page and custom page layouts anyways and you are not in need of all the css that's inside of SharePoint?